How to Use a New Firebase Firestore Database (Multi-Region 'nam5') in a Flutter Project
Problem:
I have an existing Firebase project where I've created a new Firestore database in the 'nam5' multi-region location, named 'newDb', to improve efficiency. However, I am facing issues with setting up my Flutter project so that all Firestore operations are performed on this new database, instead of the default one.
Code:
Here's a snippet of my current setup:
In Main.dart
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

In firebase_options.dart
  static const FirebaseOptions web = FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: 'xAIzaSyBISlt7cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    appId: '1:xxxxxxxxxxxxx:web:xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    projectId: 'xxxxx-ctd29',
    authDomain: 'xxxxx-ctd29.firebaseapp.com',
    storageBucket: 'xxxxx-ctd29.appspot.com',
    measurementId: 'G-xxxxxxxxxx',
  );

  static const FirebaseOptions android = FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: 'AIzaSyAu8is_gfH5_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    appId: '1:xxxxxxxxxxxxx:android:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    projectId: 'xxxxx-ctd29',
    storageBucket: 'xxxxxx-ctd29.appspot.com',
  );

Issue:
Despite setting up my project with the new configurations, all Firestore operations are still interacting with the default database instead of 'newDb'.
What I’ve Tried:
I’ve initialized Firebase with DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform, expecting it to connect to the 'newDb' database. However, the operations continue to be directed to the default database, and I need guidance on how to properly configure my Flutter project to use the 'newDb' database for all Firestore operations.

Security rules is also not working for new database

It sounds like you have a project with multiple Firestore databases and you want to use a non-default database in your Flutter app.
That is something that is not controlled by the FirebaseOptions (if you check the values, you see that nothing in there identifies a specific Firestore database). Instead, you can specify the database name when you get the Firestore instance by using the instanceFor factory method and its databaseId parameter.
So:
final db = FirebaseFirestore.instanceFor(Firebase.app(), "your non-default database ID");


This Work Its reflecting in non-default database
but  due to Security Rules
function isLoggedIn() {
return request.auth != null;
}
match /users/{userId} {
allow read: if isLoggedIn();
allow write: if isLoggedIn(); // Write access only for logged-in users.
}


security rules is not working for new database

I answered how to access a non-default Firestore database in your project, which was your original question and seems to work. If you have additional questions, please post those separately. --- Also see: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers]
